# Hibernate OGM With Mongodb Count query with $gt $gte $lt $lte not working with less than 1

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, jackson, hibernate-ogm

I am using Hibernate OGM (5.2.0.Alpha1) with Mongodb (3.4)

I executed Mongodb Count Query Using Hibernate OGM by 2 below way

(1). Count query using Mongodb count query `db.tablename.count({..})`

(2). Count query by Mongodb Aggregate query...

Description

(1). Count query using Mongodb count query `db.tablename.count({..})`

```
public long executeCountQuery(){

    //below line Works fine because value is 1.3 with $lt
    //String query= "db.sales_stone_details.count({'$and':[{'size' : { '$lt' : 1.3}}]})" 

    //below line gots Error because value is 0.3(less than 1) with $lt
    String query= "db.sales_stone_details.count({'$and':[{'size' : { '$lt' : 0.3}}]})"   

    long count = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query.toString()).getSingleResult();
    return count;
}
```

(2). Count query by Mongodb  Aggregate query...

```
public long executeCountQuery(){

    //below line Works fine because value is 1.3 with $lt
    //String query= "db.sales_stone_details.aggregate([{'$match': {'size': {'$lt': 1.3}}},{'$group': {'_id' :  ObjectId(\"59df0d28f16b004af040c38c\"), 'countForAggregate' : {'$sum' : 1}}}])"

    //below line gots Error because value is 0.3(less than 1) with $lt
    String query= "db.sales_stone_details.aggregate([{'$match': {'size': {'$lt': 0.3}}},{'$group': {'_id' :  ObjectId(\"59df0d28f16b004af040c38c\"), 'countForAggregate' : {'$sum' : 1}}}])"

    List<Stone> stones = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query.toString() , Stone.class).getResultList();

    long count = 0;
    if (stones != null || !stones.isEmpty()){
         count  = stones.get(0).getCountForAggregate();
    }

    return count;
}
```

Error

```
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'.
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.readBsonType(JsonReader.java:243) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:149) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:105) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:90) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.6.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.query.parsing.nativequery.impl.MongoDBQueryDescriptorBuilder.parseAsObject(MongoDBQueryDescriptorBuilder.java:252) ~[hibernate-ogm-mongodb-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.query.parsing.nativequery.impl.MongoDBQueryDescriptorBuilder.parse(MongoDBQueryDescriptorBuilder.java:239) ~[hibernate-ogm-mongodb-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.query.parsing.nativequery.impl.MongoDBQueryDescriptorBuilder.build(MongoDBQueryDescriptorBuilder.java:211) ~[hibernate-ogm-mongodb-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect.parseNativeQuery(MongoDBDialect.java:892) ~[hibernate-ogm-mongodb-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect.parseNativeQuery(MongoDBDialect.java:169) ~[hibernate-ogm-mongodb-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.impl.ForwardingGridDialect.parseNativeQuery(ForwardingGridDialect.java:212) ~[hibernate-ogm-core-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.query.impl.NativeNoSqlQueryInterpreter.getCustomQuery(NativeNoSqlQueryInterpreter.java:50) ~[hibernate-ogm-core-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.query.impl.NativeNoSqlQueryInterpreter.createQueryPlan(NativeNoSqlQueryInterpreter.java:45) ~[hibernate-ogm-core-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.10.Final.jar:5.1.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.hibernatecore.impl.OgmSessionImpl.list(OgmSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-ogm-core-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.ogm.query.impl.NoSQLQueryImpl.list(NoSQLQueryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-ogm-core-5.2.0.Alpha1.jar:5.2.0.Alpha1]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.10.Final.jar:5.1.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.10.Final.jar:5.1.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7512.getSingleResult(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.techhive.sales.service.impl.GenericModelDaoImpl.executeCountQuery(GenericModelDaoImpl.java:621) ~[classes/:na]
...............
...........
```

I got same error with `$gt , $lte , $gte` operators also.

But it seems like `$gt , $gte , $lt , $lte` is not working with less than 1 value..

Is I am right???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 11/01/2018**: This issue should be fixed in the next release: 5.2

Yes, you are right. You found a bug. I've created an issue for it and it should be fixed in the next release: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-1371

Comment: Hi David ,Thanks for Reply.

Also check 0 with other MongoDb Query Aggregation Elements.

Example : 
I also check 0 is not working with Mongodb Aggregation Elements like '$arrayElemAt'.

`Works Fine : db.test.aggregate({$project:{first: {'$arrayElemAt': [['Name'], 1]}}})`

`Error : db.test.aggregate({$project:{first: {'$arrayElemAt': [['Name'], 0]}}})`

Comment: We merged the fix in master, it should work in the next release. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: ok thanks Davide..
Can you tell me the approximate days for next release??
Actually my project is running and i have to implement this 0-1 range queries in it...

Comment: I don't know actually, I need to finish the issues in the release 5.2.CR1: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/OGM/versions/31605/tab/release-report-todo

Comment: Hi Davide , May be 2 more issue i think.... Please read below 2 links.
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319793/hibernate-ogm-aggregate-query-result-not-working-with-primitive-types

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294248/hibernate-ogm-with-mongodb-result-of-2nd-query-on-same-table-dependent-on-result#

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look